# How to expand special characters inside lstinline?

Tags: listings

I have some inline code I want to use some special characters with.

The desired result:

```
`CMD ...`
```

Working Tex without `lstinline`:

```
\textasciigrave CMD \ldots\textasciigrave
```

However, when I try to put the Tex inside `\lstinline{}`, the special characters no longer expand correctly, instead giving me the raw Tex code. The backticks don't look right when I just use `` ` `` and the LaTeX checker complains that I should use `\ldots` instead of `...`.

Is there a way to get the special characters to expand as I want inside `lstinline`?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX stackexchange. Please, provide a full code example when asking a question. You also should at least mention that you are using the `listings` package, where the `listinline` macro is from.

Comment: The main scope in life for `\lstinline` is to type verbatim its argument ;-). Are you sure you don't simply want `\texttt{\textasciigrave CMD \ldots\textasciigrave}` (that is, a change of font to monospaced)?

Comment: @Rmano Yeah that works. I'll use `texttt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\lstinline` is part of the `listings` package and it is used to print "verbatim" its content, that is, it jumps into loops to *avoid* interpreting any commands (there are exceptions and options, but mainly that is the main objective of the command) in order to be able to typeset code.

If what you need is the monospaced fonts, just use:

```latex
\texttt{\textasciigrave CMD \ldots\textasciigrave}
```

which prints the (evaluated!) content in the current monospaced font.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue 1:**

Nowadays LaTeX "assumes" .tex-input-files being encoded in utf8 and therefore  with traditional single-octet/single-byte/8-bit TeX-engines by default loads the inputenc-package with option "utf8".

But the listings-package dates back to times when single-octet-/single-byte-/8-bit-encodings were the state of the art for encoding text files like .tex-source code.

When running traditional non-utf-8-engines based on TeX or pdfTeX the listings-package does not support multi-octet-encodings like utf8 but only supports single-octet/8bit-encodings—[section "2.5 Special characters" of the manual of the listings package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf#subsection.2.5) says:

> Thus, **if you use the a package that supports multibyte characters,** such as the CJK or ucs packages for Chinese and UTF-8 characters, **you must avoid letting listings process the extended characters.** It is generally best to also specify `extendedchars=false` to avoid having listings get entangled in the other package's extended-character treatment.

If you insist in doing things using the listings-package with an utf8-encoded .tex-input-file, running a traditional non-utf-8 TeX-engine, then make sure that the routines belonging to the listings-package only get characters to process that in utf8 are assigned to 7-bit (single-octet) code points denoting the ASCII-subset.

Alternatively consider using the [listingsutf8](https://ctan.org/pkg/listingsutf8)-package and only the command `\lstinputlisting`.

**Issue 2:**

The `\lstinline`-command does not support the keys for escaping to LaTeX described in section ["4.3.13 Escaping to LaTeX" of the manual of the listings package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf#subsubsection.4.3.13). There is one exception known to me: `mathescape`. So, if you don't mind the drawbacks with this, you can inside a math-escape use the `\text`-command.

---

If using utf8-encoded .tex-input-files, then

- either use a TeX-engine based on XeTeX or LuaTeX whose "native" internal character-representation-scheme is unicode and which therefore in any case tokenizes a multibyte-utf8-character as a single character-token.
- or, if using a traditional TeX-engine based on TeX or pdfTeX (, where each octet/byte of a utf8-character will be tokenized as a character-token on its own and where possible leading octets/bytes of sequences of multiple bytes denoting a multibyte-character are made active and—for triggering insertion of the correct glyph—are defined to "look at" subsequent character-tokens coming from tokenizing continuation-octets/bytes), make sure that all the arguments of the routines of the listings-package only process characters which in utf8 are assigned to 7-bit (single-octet) code points denoting the ASCII-subset.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
%%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%%\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%
% Either have the .tex-input-file encoded in a single-byte-encoding and use inputenc.
% Or use a native-utf8-engine like LuaTeX or XeTeX.
% Or make sure the routines of the listings-package don't encounter multi-octet-characters.
%
\lstset{%
  language={[LaTeX]TeX},
  basicstyle=\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont,
  commentstyle=\bfseries,
}

\begin{document}

Test Text  \textasciigrave CMD \ldots\textasciigrave\space Test Text 

Test Text
%
% Either have the .tex-input-file encoded in a single-byte-encoding and use inputenc.
% Or use a native-utf8-engine like LuaTeX or XeTeX.
% Or make sure the routines of the listings-package don't encounter multi-octet-characters.
%
\lstinline[mathescape]|Listing $\text{\normalfont\textasciigrave CMD \ldots\textasciigrave}$ Listing| 
Text Text

Test Text
%
% Either have the .tex-input-file encoded in a single-byte-encoding and use inputenc.
% Or use a native-utf8-engine like LuaTeX or XeTeX.
% Or make sure the routines of the listings-package don't encounter multi-octet-characters.
%
\lstinline[mathescape]|Listing $\text{\textasciigrave CMD \ldots\textasciigrave}$ Listing| 
Text Text

\end{document}
```

[image]